# Decimal to Hexadecimal Functions in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a program that communicates to a device through the serial port. I am having difficulties with one section however. I am getting what looks like a right angle symbol when I run through the calculated hexadecimal commands. Here are the two sections of code (main section and function).

Main Section:

```
private: System::Void poll_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
     {
            int i, end;
            double a = 1.58730159;
            String^ portscan = "port";
            String^ translate;
            std::string portresponse [65];
            std::fill_n(portresponse, 65, "Z");

            for (i=0;i<63;i++)
            {
                if(this->_serialPort->IsOpen)
                {
                    // Command 0 generator
                    int y = 2;
                    y += i;
                    std::string command0[10] = {"0xFF", "0xFF", "0xFF", "0xFF", "0xFF", "0x02", dectohex(i), "0x00", "0x00", dectohex(y)};

                    // The two "dectohex" values above is where I get the odd symbol

                    for (end=0;end<10;end++)
                    {
                        portscan = marshal_as<String^>( command0[end] );
                        this->_serialPort->WriteLine(portscan);
                    }

                    translate = (this->_serialPort->ReadLine());
                    MarshalString(translate, portresponse [i]);
                    if(portresponse [i] != "Z")
                    {
                        comboBox7->Items->Add(i);
                    }
                    this->progressBar1->Value=a;
                    a += 1.58730159;
                }
            }


     }
```

Function:

```
string dectohex(int i)
     {
        string hexidecimal = "";
        char hex_string[10] = "";
        hexidecimal = sprintf (hex_string, "0x%02X", i);
        return hexidecimal;
     }
```

I am assuming that there is something fairly simple that I am missing. Any and all help is appreciated.

---

The solution:
Per David Yaw's guidance.

```
    string dectohex(int i)
         {
            char hex_array[10];
            sprintf (hex_array, "0x%02X", i);
            string hex_string(hex_array);
            return string(hex_string);
         }
```

Comment: Before one can write readable C++, one must learn how to spell hexadecimal.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I must have missed that in my haste to try and remedy my code. I'm just glad I didn't miss it in the title or description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `sprintf` isn't a string, as you have coded currently. It's the number of characters written to the `char*` that was passed in as the first parameter. Use the character buffer that you passed in, and convert the `char*` to a string object.

```
string dectohex(int i)
{
    char hex_string[10];
    sprintf (hex_string, "0x%02X", i);
    return string(hex_string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sprintf ....
Use a **[stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)** instead.

```
#include <sstream>

string dectohex(int i)
{
    stringstream str;
    str << std::hex << i;
    return str.str();
}
```

To get the exact same text as you had before:

```
 str << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << i;
```

Comment: Awesome, I don't get the weird symbol anymore but now I am getting 0 and 2. If I am following that correctly that means that the dectohex function is not sending a value back other than what is given to it (y in this case). Is there something I should be adding in the function itself to complete the conversion/storage of the conversion? (I've tried looking stringstream up on MSDN to try and troubleshoot, however, it was little to no help)

Comment: @Andy I've updates the answer so you'll get the exact same result as before.

Comment: I've tried this putting "str << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << i;" right before the return statement and it is now formatting it with a ten digit in front of the x. For example: if i = 1 it is coming out with 10x01. Is it multiplying by 10?