# Send Hex Bytes To A Serial Port

Tags: c++, c++-cli, hex

I am attempting to send hexadecimal bytes to a serial com port. The issue is that the segment that sends the command apparently wants a system string instead of an integer (error C2664 "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'System::String ^'). I have looked for a way to send an integer instead but have had no luck. (I have tried sending string representations of the hexadecimal values, but the device did not recognize the commands)

Main part of Code

```
private: System::Void poll_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
            int i, end;
            double a = 1.58730159;
            String^ portscan = "port";
            String^ translate;
            std::string portresponse [65];
            std::fill_n(portresponse, 65, "Z");

            for (i=1;i<64;i++)
            {
                if(this->_serialPort->IsOpen)
                {
                    // Command 0 generator
                    int y = 2;
                    y += i;
                    int command0[10] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x02, dectohex(i), 0x00, 0x00, dectohex(y)};

                    for (end=0;end<10;end++)
                    {
                        this->_serialPort->WriteLine(command0[end]);
                    }

                    translate = (this->_serialPort->ReadLine());
                    MarshalString(translate, portresponse [i]);
                    if(portresponse [i] != "Z")
                    {
                        comboBox7->Items->Add(i);
                    }
                    this->progressBar1->Value=a;
                    a += 1.58730159;
                }
            }


     }
```

Here is the function dectohex:

```
    int dectohex(int i)
         {
            int x = 0;
            char hex_array[10];
            sprintf (hex_array, "0x%02X", i);
            string hex_string(hex_array);
            x = atoi(hex_string.c_str());
            return x;
         }
```

---

This is what solved my problem, courtesy of Jochen Kalmbach

```
auto data = gcnew array<System::Byte> { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x02, 0xBF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xBD };
_serialPort->Write(data, 0, data->Length);
```

Replaced this

```
this->_serialPort->WriteLine(command0[end]);
```

Comment: You should not mix C++/CLI and C++... that nakes no sence... it makes it even harder to maintain your code... so please remove `std::string` and replace it with `String^`!

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081196/decimal-to-hexadecimal-functions-in-c-cli

Comment: Okay, I can't do that because the String^ cannot hold the array that is intended. This is the same code segment but dealing with a different part. The previous post was an issue I was having with the dectohex function. Now it is with serial communication, but I can see where the same segment would lead you to think that.

Comment: You should probably `Write` an `array<byte>` instead of using `WriteLine`. But what on earth does `dectohex` do? Bytes aren't decimal or hexadecimal, those are just different representations of their values. `0x7` is exactly the same thing as `7`. And `07`.

Comment: I have posted the function now. Correct, but 0x3F is 63 correct? I apparently need to send hexadecimal bytes to a device in order for it to understand the commands. I will try your suggestion above. Thank you.

Comment: @Hans: There is only `Write` or `WriteLine`.... no `WriteByte`...

Comment: @Andy There's no such thing as a hexadecimal byte, unless you represent it as a string, which apparently you shouldn't. Both `0x3F` and `63` become 00111111 when represented as eight binary bits, which is what's sent through the port.

Comment: @Jochen - SerialPort.BaseStream.WriteByte().  But sounds like he has an encoding problem buried somewhere as well, 0x3f == '?'

Comment: @molbdnilo so no matter what is sent (string, hex, decimal) it inevitably becomes binary? If that is the case I could possibly send just binary for everything.

I apologize everyone for the difficulties, I am very new to coding..

Comment: @Andy That doesn't make sense. The computer is binary. Numbers are the same regardless of which number system you write them in. No matter what you send, it will be sent through the serial port as a series of electric pulses representing ones and zeroes.

Comment: `int dextohex(int i) { return i; }` - isn't it much more simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sent an integer over a serial line.... you can only sent BYTES (7-8 bit)!

You need to choose what you want to do:

- Sent characters: So the "number" 12 will be converted into the bytes

  ```
  _serialPort->Write(12.ToString());
  // => 0x49, 0x50
  ```
- Sent the integer (4 bytes) as little endian

  ```
  auto data = System::BitConverter::GetBytes(12);
  _serialPort->Write(data, 0, data->Length);
  // => 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
  ```
- Or you write just a single byte:

  ```
  auto data = gcnew array<System::Byte> { 12 };
  _serialPort->Write(data, 0, data->Length);
  // => 0x0c
  ```
- Or write an byte array:

  ```
  auto data = gcnew array<System::Byte> { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x02, 0xBF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xBD };
  _serialPort->Write(data, 0, data->Length);
  // => 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x02 0xBF 0x00 0x00 0xBD
  ```

Comment: So no matter what approach I take I can't send, for example, 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x02 0xBF 0x00 0x00 0xBD as it appears here? I am trying to send these values to an external device to give me information about that same device. Is this additional information helpful?

Comment: What is the problem with : `auto data = gcnew array<System::Byte>(10) { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x02, 0xBF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xBD}; _serialPort->Write(data, 0, data->Length);´

Comment: I was testing it and it sets up no issues, but when I run the program it gives me an output of "FF FF FF A0 03 00 6F 00" according to a serial port monitor. It seems like to get one iteration of FF being sent you need to send 2 0xFF, which I am at a loss for.

Comment: I think you are using the worng baud rate or wrong settings for the port... can you show us your settings??? and the requested settings?

Comment: I will find where the settings are and add them above (are you wanting the physical settings for the port, the program settings or both?). As for the baud rate (in program), it is variable based on what the user chooses although none of them yield the correct results.

Comment: Relevant are: BaudRate, DataBits, DiscardNull, DtrEnable, Handshake, Parity, ParityReplace, RtsEnable, StopBits, WriteTimeout . See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! I had errors in how the Parity and DataBits were set up. I set them back to the None and 8 respectively and it works flawlessly.